# Laravel 5 BadMethodCallException when using with()

Tags: laravel, table-relationships

I have been struggling with this issue for the past 5 hours and It is driving me nuts.

First here is my code.

There is a product contrloller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller {

    protected $product;

    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index','show']]); 
    }
```

a few methods and then the edit method

```
public function edit($id)
{ 
    //$products         = $this->product->findBySlug($slug);
    $products           = $this->product->with('images' )->find($id);
    dd($products);


}
```

The Product model:

```
<?php namespace  App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class Product extends Model implements SluggableInterface {

    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $guarded = array();


    protected $sluggable = array(
        'build_from' => 'title',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    );


    public static $rules = array(
        'type'         => 'required',
        'price'        => 'required',
        'title'        => 'required' 
    );

    protected $fillable = [
        'shorturl',
        'url',
        'type',
        'title',
        'slug',
        'overview',
        'price',
        'availability'
    ];



    /**
     * through product_tags pivot table
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
    }



    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }



}
```

and the Image model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'title'      => 'required',
        'url'        => 'required',
        'product_id' => 'required'
    );

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'url',
        'size'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

}
```

My problem is that when I run

```
$products           = $this->product->find($id);
```

I get the record I am looking for. If however I use

```
$products           = $this->product->with('images' )->find($id);
```

I then get the following error.

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 1990:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::images()
```

and the first few lines are:

```
in Builder.php line 1990
at Builder->__call('images', array())
at Builder->images()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'images'), array()) in Builder.php line 933
at Builder->__call('images', array())
at Builder->images()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'images'), array()) in Model.php line 3323
at Model->__call('images', array()) in Builder.php line 451
at Product->images() in Builder.php line 451
at Builder->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Relation.php line 158
```

I can post the rest if you would like but I think my error is something quite fundamental that I am missing.

Here is the full stack trace

```
in Builder.php line 1990
at Builder->__call('images', array())
at Builder->images()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'images'), array()) in Builder.php line 933
at Builder->__call('images', array())
at Builder->images()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'images'), array()) in Model.php line 3323
at Model->__call('images', array()) in Builder.php line 451
at Product->images() in Builder.php line 451
at Builder->Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
at call_user_func(object(Closure)) in Relation.php line 158
at Relation::noConstraints(object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 452
at Builder->getRelation('images') in Builder.php line 422
at Builder->loadRelation(array(object(Product)), 'images', object(Closure)) in Builder.php line 402
at Builder->eagerLoadRelations(array(object(Product))) in Builder.php line 169
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 136
at Builder->first(array('*')) in Builder.php line 84
at Builder->find('4') in ProductController.php line 117
at ProductController->edit('4')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ProductController), 'edit'), array('products' => '4')) in Controller.php line 246
at Controller->callAction('edit', array('products' => '4')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 162
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ProductController), object(Route), 'edit') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 107
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 47
at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 108
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ProductController), object(Route), object(Request), 'edit') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 67
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController', 'edit') in Route.php line 198
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 131
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 693
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 660
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 178
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image model you posted has a class name Product.

If it's your actual code then:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

the App\Image class used in this relationship does not exist.

Comment: If that's the case the actual problem is not the non-existing `Image` class but the fact that the wrong `Product` class is injected into the controller

Comment: Thank you user3384745. Its always the little things :-( I am soooo embarrased by this

Answer (score -1):

If you carefully examine the stack trace `Model->__call('images', array())` it clearly due to the fact it not calling `with()` method from within `Product` (because it is static).

You should however be able to the following:

```
$products = $this->product->newQuery()->with('images')->find(1);
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. Added the full stack trace to the post.

Comment: Are you certain you have `public function images() { }` in your `Product` class (I don't see that in the code you post but I assume that just a typo).